# XMLHttpRequest cannot load API URL. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: c#, angularjs, api, wcf, model-view-controller

[It shows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKycM.png)

Got this error when we call API on Remote Acess server from VPN.

We already mentioned in API's web config below code:

```
 <bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webWinBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="100000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
 ........ 
........

   <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:58319" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

still getting an error when we call API.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://test/service1.svc/User/GetLogin. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

We search some google link, but no luck, my question is can we add code to bypass the security or support the security which calls web API in Chrome.

Comment: you wana to compromise the api cross origin security?

Comment: No, we are not able to touch the web API, in IE code works, but Chrome gives 401 'unauthorized' related error. the question is any code for chrome that hit the web API, right now it through error without post web API. , see in the console.